# Why won't this div appear after I click another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm pretty experienced with programming, but I am just getting new to Javascript. I am making a new element when I click a div, but it won't work. I have tried many methods, and this one seems like the simplest. Can you help me figure out what is wrong?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="head">
            <h1>Corkboard</h1>
            <div id="addNote" onclick="showNewNoteMenu()">+</div>
        </div>

        <div id = "newNoteMenu">
            <div class="container">
                <input id="title" type="text" placeholder="Title" name="Title"/> <br />
                <textarea id="details" cols=22.5 rows=5></textarea> <br />
                <div onclick="createNewNote()" id='submitNewNote'>Make New Note</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="content" onclick="hideNewNoteMenu()">

        </div>
    </body>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

```
    function showNewNoteMenu() {
        document.getElementById("newNoteMenu").style.display = "inline-block";
    };

    function hideNewNoteMenu() {
        document.getElementById("newNoteMenu").style.display = "none";
    };

    function createNewNote() {
        document.getElementsByTagName("h1").innerHTML = "This works"
        alert("OK");
        var title = document.getElementById("title").value;
        var text = document.getElementById("details").value;
        var date = new Date();
            var hours = date.getHours();
            var minutes = date.getMinutes();
        var time = hours + ":" + minutes;
        var content = document.getElementsByClassName("content");

        var note = '<div class="note"><div class="container"><h2>'+ title + '</h2><i>' + time + '</i><p>' + text + '</p></div></div>';


    }

    hideNewNoteMenu();
```

Comment: NOTE: The javascript is in the right place, the question got formatted wrong.

Comment: is that javascript at the top of your page or at the end? are you getting any errors in the console? I think you might be getting one that says `showNewNoteMenu is not defined(...)`

Comment: Why are you including jQuery but not using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears all that's missing is to insert the string of markup, `note`, into the `document`.

In this case, you can use [`.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML):

```
var content = document.getElementsByClassName("content");
var note = /* ... */;

content[0].insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', note);
```

With `beforeend`, it will insert the `note` as the `content`'s last child.

Also, the use of `[0]` is because `getElementsByClassName()` returns a collection of Elements (note the plural `getElements...`).

---

Since you've included jQuery, this could also be accomplished with [`jQuery(html)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) and [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/):

```
$(note).appendTo(content[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
<div id="addNote" onclick="showNewNoteMenu()">+</div>
```

to

```
<div id="addNote">+</div>
```

and

```
document.getElementById("addNode").addEventListener("click",showNewNoteMenu);
```

Be sure the JavaScript executes after the page has been loaded and parsed.  You should have a window.onload.

Comment: Being unobtrusive, separating code from markup, may be considered more ideal. But, as long as the functions are global, the `onclick` attribute should work as expected.

Comment: The "note" still won't show on the page, any thoughts for that?

Comment: Are you adding the note into the DOM?  Creating the string doesn't add it to the page.  You would need to use **document.createTextNode** and **document.createElement**, then **appendChild**.